# Can't get button press to work in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Ok I'm pretty new to flutter/ dart so go easy on me.  I'm just trying to make a very simple app where when you press a button some text updates telling you how many times you have pressed the button.  I have no idea why this code doesn't work.   The button appears but nothing happens when you press it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Homepage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[],
    );
  }
}

class Buttonz extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ButtonBeingPressed createState() => new _ButtonBeingPressed();
}

class _ButtonBeingPressed extends State<Buttonz> {
  int _timesPressed = 0;
  _buttonWasPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _timesPressed++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(children: <Widget>[
     new Center(
          child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text(
              'The button was pressed ' + _timesPressed.toString() + "         
 times"),
          new RaisedButton(
            onPressed: _buttonWasPressed(),
           child: new Row(
              children: <Widget>[new Text("Press meh")],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ))
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Having Center in Column is of no use. Rather use Column in Center.

Answer (score 12):

Your problem is that you didn't pass a callback to `RaisedButton`, you invoked your callback.

```
new RaisedButton(
  onPressed: _buttonWasPressed(), // invokes function
  child: new Row(children: <Widget>[new Text("Press meh")]),
);
```

To pass a callback to another widget you have two choices:

### Pass a tear-off

```
 new RaisedButton(
   onPressed: _buttonWasPressed, // no `()`,
   child: ...
 )
```

### Pass a closure

```
 new RaisedButton(
   onPressed: () {
     // do something.
   },
   ..
 )
```

Comment: It worked.  I understand it now.   Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 4):

in some cases, this can occur with a widget in the stack.

It is possible that the Widget is overwritten with another Widget, so it cannot be clicked.

Comment: if it happen, then how will you solve it? coz it happens to me now, tq

Comment: @MNFS it happens too in my case. I just make sure the outer widget is not filled the inner widget.

Answer (score 0):

Added a Material App and rewired the RaisedButton a little. I think it was how you had `onPressed` wired up.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(home: new Buttonz());
  }
}

class Buttonz extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ButtonBeingPressed createState() => new _ButtonBeingPressed();
}

class _ButtonBeingPressed extends State<Buttonz> {
  int _timesPressed = 0;
  _buttonWasPressed() {
    setState(() {
      _timesPressed++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Text(
            'The button was pressed $_timesPressed times'),
        new RaisedButton(
          child: const Text('Press meh'),
          onPressed: () {
            _buttonWasPressed();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your button should be like this.:

```
new RaisedButton( 
    child: const Text('Press meh'), 
    onPressed: _buttonWasPressed, 
),
```

If this doesn't work, then try to clean your `flutter` project with `flutter clean` and then reinstalling the app on debug device.