# Using function inside a button in flutter does not behave as expected

Tags: flutter, dart

I have made a class for a button to redesign it and use it in all my app

```
  const PrimaryButton({
    Key key,
    @required this.text,
    @required this.paddingH,
    this.press,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final VoidCallback press;
  final double paddingH;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: press,
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: AppTheme.hexColor,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: paddingH),
        elevation: 2,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
      ),
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 15, letterSpacing: 2.2, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to change the type from voidCallback to  Function or void but it did not work.

Example from my code where the problem is:

```
                  PrimaryButton(
                    text: "SAVE",
                    press:  submitPassword,
                    paddingH: 30,
                  ),
```

I want to pass this function inside the PrimaryButton

```
    submitPassword() {
    if (newPassword.text == confirmPassword.text) {
      debugPrint("if");
    } else {
      debugPrint("else");
      BotController()
          .botText("passwords do not mach\n write them again please");
    }
  }
```

But it did not work, it gives me always the debugPrint("if");

I think it is a problem with calling the function, but I could not figure it out.

I saw this answer but it did not help me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50361572/13470875

what is the solution and why does this happen? And thanks

Comment: print out the `newPassword.text` & `confirmPassword.text` when tapping the button to check what those variables have stored at that time.

Comment: "it gives me always the debugPrint("if")" that means both `newPassword ` and `confirmPassword ` are equal. most probably empty string. it would be helpful to share textfield code part

Comment: Thank you, it was a problem with assigning the TextEditingController  @esentis

Comment: @JahidulIslam yes they are equal, I made a mistake with assigning the proper TextEditingController, Thank you